# iOS FBSDK v4 loginbuttondidlogout unrecognized selector

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, unrecognized-selector

I set up the Facebook login correctly (I'm able to log in using the Facebook button and retrieve the profile data). I followed The FB Developer guide to set up the SSK and the LoginButton. 
The issue arise when I go back the button and I want to log off. This is what I get:

> -[UILabel loginButtonDidLogout:]:  unrecognized selector sent to instance xxxxxxx
>
> ***Terminationg App due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UILabel
>   loginButtonDidLogout:]:  unrecognized selector sent to instance xxxxxx'

The class Is loaded in the appDelegate file with

> [FBSDKLoginButton class];

in the .plist application file the -ObjC switch is set in the linker section.

Any ideas?? Thanks in advance

Comment: Update your question with the code causing the exception.

Comment: there's no specific code related to the question! I just followed this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started and this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/v2.3

Comment: You posted a question about a runtime exception in your app. Of course there is specific code. Post your code causing the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue! I was migrating from Facebook SDK v3.4 to v4. As I had a view already done for the previous login Button, I just recycled it and changed the class as the tutorial says. Deleting the view from the Storyboard, adding a new view and changing class to `FBSDKLoginButton` made everything work smoothly.

Thanks anyway rmaddy!